# clang-tidy Xcode static analyzer integration

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, compilation, clang

I’ve added clang-tidy capabilities into my CMake project. However, when it use to generate an Xcode project using the `-G Xcode` option, the `CXX_CLANG_TIDY` option is missing, only using makefile I can see that the clang-tidy is being properly set.

Here’s the CMake command

```
  option(ENABLE_CLANG_TIDY "default is off" OFF)

  if(ENABLE_CLANG_TIDY)
    find_program(CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy)
    if(CLANG_TIDY)
      string(
        CONCAT
          clang_tidy_cmd
          "${CLANG_TIDY}\;-config={Checks: '"
          "*,"
          "-google-runtime-references,"
          .... <more flags> ... )
           set_target_properties(${my_target} PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY
                                                      ${clang_tidy_cmd})
```

Any idea why does the Xcode generator option (`-G Xcode`) it's omitting the clang-tidy configuration from the compilation, and when setting CMake to generate simple makefile, the clang-tidy reappears in the compilation line of each cpp file ?

Is it a bug ? my CMake version is 3.20.2

From looking into this problem, there seem to be no support for clang-tidy in xcode, but there must be some workaround since the clang-tidy is just like any other compilation flag which is added to the compilation command.

Comment: "Is it a bug?" - Probably, not. This specified in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html) for the property `<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY`: "The Makefile Generators and the Ninja generator will run this tool along with the compiler and report a warning if the tool reports any problems."

Comment: You're right, this cmake command behaves as expected, but i'm wondering if it's possible to check xcode build command so that it will include the clang-tidy rules.